# How can split a string on "\" in java?

Tags: java, split

I have a problem with Java split function
how can I split a string on `"\"` like that, for example the text `hello\world`?
My code is such that:

```
str1 = "hello\\world";
String[] parts=str1.split("\\");
```

Comment: just to add to Thomas Mueller's answer - `\w` this escape the w.. not sure if it will even compile.

Comment: @user3232244: I don't think you actually have "hello\world" in your Java source code, but I guess you have such data in a database or so. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
String[] parts="hello\\world".split("\\\\");
```

The `\` is the [escape character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) and needs to be escaped in a String (for Java, C, C++, and similar languages), that's why it's `"hello\\world"` and not just `"hello\world"`.

In a regular expression (and `String.split` uses regular expressions), the `\` character is *also* the escape character. So now we have two levels of escaping: the Java String escaping, and the [regular expression escaping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). That's why you need to write four `\`: two for the regular expression syntax, and then you need to duplicate both for Java escaping. Regular expression escaping is not specific for Java; other languages such as [PHP also use the `\` as the escape character for regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to escaping the backslash character you can use [`quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String[] parts = str1.split(Pattern.quote("\\"));
```